# Dispatch NgRx actions only when some properties changes on Rxjs Polling

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have a Rxjs Polling effect like so :

```
updateProductData$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.loadProduct),
    switchMap(_) =>
      this.http.get('endpoint').pipe(
        delay(1000),
        repeat(),
        switchMap((data) => [
          fromActions.updateFoo({foo: data.foo}),
          fromActions.updateBar({bar: data.bar}),
        ])
      )
    )
  );
```

How can I dispatch `updateFoo` and `updateBar` only when `data.foo` or `data.bar` change respectively?

I can improve this by using `distinctUntilChanged`, doing so the actions wont trigger if `data.stuff` changes, however, both actions still dispatch when either one changes.

```
...
     repeat(),
     distinctUntileChanged((prev, curr) => prev.foo === curr.foo && prev.bar === curr.bar) // works but it fires both actions when either one changes
     switchMap((data) => [
       fromActions.updateFoo({foo: data.foo}),
       fromActions.updateBar({bar: data.bar}),
     ])
```

I want to dispatch `updateFoo` when `data.foo` changes and `updateBar` when `data.bar` changes, knowing that `data` has a lot of other properties that can change as time goes on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be an approach:

```js
updateProductData$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.loadProduct),
    switchMap(_) =>
      this.http.get('endpoint').pipe(
        delay(1000),
        repeat(),
        
        multicast(
          new Subject(),
          source => merge(
            // concerning `foo`
            source.pipe(
              distinctUntilChanged((prev, crt) => prev.foo === crt.foo),
              map(data => fromActions.updateFoo({foo: data.foo})),
            ),

            // concerning `bar`
            source.pipe(
              distinctUntilChanged((prev, crt) => prev.bar === crt.bar),
              map(data => fromActions.updateBar({bar: data.bar})),
            ),
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

The `source` from `multicast`'s second argument is the instance of the Subject which has been declared as the first argument. By using `multicast`, we can divide the problem into 2 other smaller problems, without redundantly subscribing to the source(that's why a Subject has been used).

Comment: the effect doesnt seem to return any action, VScode complains about that. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GreatHawkeye I don't see why it wouldn't return. Apart from type errors, are there any other errors? Maybe you could add some code related to that?

Comment: You were right, it was a typo! However, both actions fire one time at the beginning, then it works properly : the polling goes on until foo or bar changes then it dispatch the actions. Any idea why the actions fire at the beginning? It obviosuly because at the beginning prev.foo === curr.foo is true but why?

Comment: @GreatHawkeye I wouldn't say that is the reason, but it's more likely due to how [`distinctUntilChanged` works](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/distinctUntilChanged.ts#L167). As you can see, there is a check to determine whether it's the first emitted value or not. I assume this is way both emit at the beginning. But this behavior can be avoided, if that's what you're after.

Comment: Just one remark: multicast(new Subject(), selector) == publish(selector)

Comment: https://ncjamieson.com/calling-publish-with-a-selector/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `pairwise` operator to get the previous state and explicitly check for the previous value. I've used `startWith(null)` to trigger the emission for the first value from the HTTP request. Without it, it won't start emitting until the second call

```js
stop$ = new Subject<any>();
poll$ = timer(0, 1000).pipe(
  startWith(null),          // <-- emit `[null, data]` for first emission
  switchMap(this.http.get('endpoint')),
  pairwise(),
  map((data) => ({
    foo: {prev: data[0].foo, current: data[1].foo},
    bar: {prev: data[0].bar, current: data[1].bar}
  })),
  takeUntil(stop$)
);

updateProductData$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromActions.loadProduct),
    switchMap(_ =>
      poll$.pipe(
        switchMap((data) => {
          let result = [];

          if (data.foo.prev && data.foo.prev !== data.foo.current) 
            result.push(fromActions.updateFoo({foo: data.foo}))
          if (data.bar.prev && data.bar.prev !== data.bar.current) 
            result.push(fromActions.updateBar({bar: data.bar}))

          return result;
        })
      )
  )
);
```

Note: I've not used NgRX and this is untested code.